# Unable to use output variables from a PowerShell script in the Override Parameters of a Resource Group deployment task in Azure DevOPS

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, output-parameter

I have a PowerShell script where I have multiple output variables generated with the following syntax :

```
Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=appObjectId;issecret=false]"+$appObjectId)
```

In the PowerShell task in Azure DevOPS, I have set the Output variables as follow:
[image]

Then, I use my output variables in an Azure Resource Group deployment as follow:
[image]

Unfortunately, when I look into the deployment details in Azure, I can see that the parameters of my ARM are not filled out with the value of the output parameters but with the name of it:
[image]

Important information: the ARM deployment task is done inside a task group. My PowerShell script is in the pipeline, just before the call to the Task Group. I tried to put the script inside the Task Group but I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause: I need to enclose the parameter "$(myParam)" in the tasks where I need to use it. Otherwise, it is not computed.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might have gotten the format wrong for defining the output variable from your Powershell script, this should work -

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=appObjectId;isOutput=true]$appObjectId"

Answer (score -1):

**Update**

**Also add is `isoutput=true`, the defaults to false**.

---

Cause you are not set the variable to **appObjectId** correctly. There is not `AADApplication.appClientid`. Then Azure DevOps treat this to string. That's why  the parameters of my ARM are not filled out with the value of the output parameters but with the name of it.

No need to use `()` to include the follow set variable command.

**SetVariable: Initialize or modify the value of a variable**

```
##vso[task.setvariable]value
```

You should use the following syntax :

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=appClientID;issecret=false;isoutput=true]value"
```

More details please refer our official doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable).

Comment: Ok I will try it. But what is strange is that when I put a "Command line" task just after the PowerShell task and use "echo $(AADApplication.appClientId)", it displays the content of the variable...

Comment: Exact same issue with the syntax you mentionned.

Comment: Hi @DavidGROSPELIER Also add `isoutput=true` when you set variable. The defaults to false. Besides, I also noticed you are  setting appObjectId, but you are trying to use **appClientID** in following  Azure Resource Group deployment. Is that a typo wrong. Please use this format `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=appClientID;issecret=false;isoutput=true]value"` and try again. Also updated the original answer.